# limit max UDP bandwidth per IP using iptables?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, denial-of-service

'm using a VPS to host a VPN for DDoS protection, but I've been wanting to find a way to rate-limit UDP traffic per IP to prevent UDP floods. I'm looking for something to only allow X MBPS of traffic to each IP, and to ignore this IP if it's traffic exceeds X MBPS

I mainly want to prevent DoS from perl/shell scripts, as these seem to still be effective in disrupting operation of the VPN

Is this possible?

If so, could someone help me out with a method of implementing this using iptables?

Comment: You want to use QoS for this, which means the `tc` command, not `iptables`.  `tc` is extremely difficult, but you can use `fireqos` and its online tutorial to setup a traffic shaping script without too much work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way myself.  High packets-per-second (pps) is (in my experience) the biggest factor in a DDoS attack.  This set of iptables rules will limit UDP pps per-ip:
`iptables -N UDPLIMIT # New chain called UDPLIMIT`

`iptables -A UDPLIMIT --match hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 300/second --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name udp_rate_limit -j ACCEPT # Only accept 300/second, ignore the rest`

`iptables -A UDPLIMIT --match limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "UDP Flood DROP: " # Log the attacker (optional)`

`iptables -A UDPLIMIT -j DROP # Drop anything over 300 pps`

Comment: You misunderstand how DDoS attacks work. By the time the packets make it to your firewall, the damage has already been done.

Comment: I'm actually in a community that is very educated in DDoS.  These rules filter most UDP based attacks, the point of these DDoS attacks is to cause an interruption in the network of the target. These rules have prevented that from happening to me for over a week.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will not prevent DDos attacks, instead it will limit the bandwidth, that means low network performance, so i suggest you to limit the number of UDP received packets per second :

1- Watch the UDP coming through the **nic**  :

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -i <nic> -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
```

2- Drop the packets exceeding  **n**  coming through your **nic** during **t** seconds :

`iptables -I INPUT -p udp -i <nic> -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds  <t> --hitcount <n> -j DROP`

Comment: It would prevent the DoS attacks, because it would only allow X MB/s per IP address, meaning if an IP address is sending 5GBPS, only X MB/s would be acknowledged.  The rest would be dropped.  https://ddosfilter.net/projects/ has a Layer 7 version of the kind of script I am looking for.  Only allow X MB/s from each separate IP address and ignore excess traffic (and possibly blacklist IPs that reach X+100MB/s for a short time, completely dropping traffic from the offending IP for ~10m)